# Issue with statically linking id3lib in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, std, id3lib

I'm trying to link id3lib statically to my XCode project.
I've found some answers in other threads suggesting to add as linker flags the full path to the .a file. This works but produces a huge number of errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::copy(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      dami::io::StringReader::readChars(unsigned char*, unsigned int) in libid3.a(tag_impl.o)
      dami::convert(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, ID3_TextEnc, ID3_TextEnc) in libid3.a(utils.o)
      dami::io::StringReader::readChars(unsigned char*, unsigned int) in libid3.a(tag_parse_lyrics3.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::compare(char const*) const", referenced from:
      ID3_TagImpl::IsV2Tag(ID3_Reader&) in libid3.a(tag_impl.o)
      dami::mm::parse(ID3_TagImpl&, ID3_Reader&) in libid3.a(tag_parse_musicmatch.o)
      dami::id3::v1::parse(ID3_TagImpl&, ID3_Reader&) in libid3.a(tag_parse_v1.o)
      dami::lyr3::v1::parse(ID3_TagImpl&, ID3_Reader&) in libid3.a(tag_parse_lyrics3.o)
      dami::lyr3::v2::parse(ID3_TagImpl&, ID3_Reader&) in libid3.a(tag_parse_lyrics3.o)
  "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      void std::__1::vector<ID3_Field*, std::__1::allocator<ID3_Field*> >::__push_back_slow_path<ID3_Field* const>(ID3_Field* const&) in libid3.a(frame_impl.o)
  "std::__1::__basic_string_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<unsigned char, std::__1::char_traits<unsigned char>, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> >::reserve(unsigned long) in libid3.a(tag.o)
      std::__1::basic_string<unsigned char, std::__1::char_traits<unsigned char>, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> >::__grow_by_and_replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned char const*) in libid3.a(tag.o)
      std::__1::basic_string<unsigned char, std::__1::char_traits<unsigned char>,
```

And so on. Again, googling suggests that the issue might be the fact the choice for standard library. Hence I tried to switch the C++ Standard Library field from "Compiler Default" to "libstdc++" (and I'm still getting the huge amount errors) or to "libc++" - and I'm getting way less errors, namely:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_compress", referenced from:
      dami::io::CompressedWriter::flush() in libid3.a(io_decorators.o)
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      dami::convert(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, ID3_TextEnc, ID3_TextEnc) in libid3.a(utils.o)
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      dami::convert(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, ID3_TextEnc, ID3_TextEnc) in libid3.a(utils.o)
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      dami::convert(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, ID3_TextEnc, ID3_TextEnc) in libid3.a(utils.o)
  "_uncompress", referenced from:
      dami::io::CompressedReader::CompressedReader(ID3_Reader&, unsigned int) in libid3.a(io_decorators.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have no idea of how to solve this. If I remove the library full path as linker flag, everything seems to work, but the library is linked dynamically (which doesn't work for me). I'm on Mac OS X 10.10; id3lib was installed via homebrew (manual installation tests led to similar results).

Does anybody have a clue?

Thanks,
Daniele

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Link Binary With Libraries* in project settings and link your project with system libraries libz (_compress, _uncompress) and libiconv ( _iconv, _iconv_close, _iconv_open).